# How Lifecycle-Aware Components is usefull in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Lifecycle-aware components perform actions in response to a change in the lifecycle status of another component, such as activities and fragments. These components help you produce better-organized, and often lighter-weight code, that is easier to maintain.

What is the use of this in real application.
Give the example or live scenarios.

What is the Use of LifecycleObserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching between coarse and fine-grained location updates. Use lifecycle-aware components to enable fine-grained location updates while your location app is visible and switch to coarse-grained updates when the app is in the background.

LiveData, a lifecycle-aware component, allows your app to automatically update the UI when your use changes locations.

Stopping and starting video buffering. Use lifecycle-aware components to start video buffering as soon as possible, but defer playback until app is fully started. You can also use lifecycle-aware components to terminate buffering when your app is destroyed.

Starting and stopping network connectivity. Use lifecycle-aware components to enable live updating (streaming) of network data while an app is in the foreground and also to automatically pause when the app goes into the background.

Pausing and resuming animated drawables. Use lifecycle-aware components to handle pausing animated drawables when while app is in the background and resume drawables after the app is in the foreground

refer this link

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

some examples

https://github.com/shashankkapsime/android-location-services-using-livedata-lifecycle-components

https://github.com/nikkijuk/LifecycleAwareRssReader

Comment: need real app live scenarios not from developer.

Comment: https://github.com/shashankkapsime/android-location-services-using-livedata-lifecycle-components

Answer (score 1):

> Lifecycle-aware components perform actions in response to a change in the lifecycle status of another component, such as activities and fragments. These components help you produce better-organized, and often lighter-weight code, that is easier to maintain.

You should read the documentation further, It's not that lengthy though ;-)

If you look at snippets written [there](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html), 
it states that, in a real time application we write plenty of code which depends on life-cycle of component(*e.g. Activity and Fragment*). So managing these considerable amount of code inside life-cycle method such as `onStart()`, `onStop()` is difficult to maintain.

Further, there is no guarantee that, code written in `onStart()` will be getting called before `onStop()`. *For example, consider you are doing some configuration check before doing operation in `onStart()` method(See the snippet below).*

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Util.checkUserStatus(result -> {
        // what if this callback is invoked AFTER activity is stopped?
        if (result) {
            myLocationListener.start();
        }
    });
}
```

*Using [Life-cycle aware components](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/package-summary.html) we can do these things in a isolated way.*

For more understanding, I will recommend this [IO/17 event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEKNi1JOrNs&t=329s).